# Extract all pivotal tracker stories

Tags: project-management

I want to download/extract all my pivotal tracker stories (as I'm moving to an alternative). If I could download them to CSV or Excel format that would be great. Want to get all stories from current, backlog + ice box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer after playing around with pivotal for a while.

- Log in to pivotal tracker
- Select Project Project
- Select Menu Project | Export CSV Select

You will be brought to new page:
Options (tick as required for my requirement I left all 3 ticked).

- All Done Stories
- All Current/Backlog Stories
- All Icebox Stories